# How to make request specs for rails controller - request not hitting controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write specs for a controller but my tests don't seem to be hitting the controller action.

My controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def elearning_course_removal
    Rails.logger.warn("warning!")
    study_group = StudyGroup.where(id: params[:study_group_id]).first
    course = Course.where(id: params[:id]).first

    if study_group && course
      Workflow.new.remove_elearning_course(study_group, course, current_user.id)
      flash[:notice] = t('study_groups.courses.remove_elearning_course.enqueue', course_name: course.name)
    else
      Rails.logger.error(elearning_removal_error(study_group, course))
      flash[:notice] = t('study_groups.courses.remove_elearning_course.enqueue_failure')
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

My test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CoursesController do
  describe '#elearning_course_removal' do
    let(:course) { FactoryBot.create(:course_with_files) }
    let(:study_group) { FactoryBot.create(:study_group) }
    let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
    let(:params) { {study_group_id: study_group.id, id: course.id, current_user: user} }

    
    it 'logs' do
      expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:warn)
      # put :elearning_course_removal, params
      controller.elearning_course_removal
    end
end
```

Calling the route like this `put :elearning_course_removal, params` in the spec just fails saying that logger wasn't called. Using the second style, `controller.elearning_course_removal` will hit my controller method, but it's not standard, and I don't know how I would pass params in this case. Its not a routing issue, as it is identifying the `controller` variable correctly.

What do I need to be able to write request specs for this controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not sending properly the params

```
RSpec.describe CoursesController do
  describe "GET elearning_course_removal" do

    let(:course) { FactoryBot.create(:course_with_files) }
    let(:study_group) { FactoryBot.create(:study_group) }
    let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
    let(:params) { {study_group_id: study_group.id, id: course.id, current_user: user} }

    it "logs" do
      expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:warn)
      put :elearning_course_removal, params: params
    end
  end
```

you can pass params like this

```
params: {study_group_id: study_group.id, id: course.id, current_user: user}
```

---

```
params: params
```

---

or directly

```
put :elearning_course_removal, params: {study_group_id: study_group.id, id: course.id, current_user: user}
```

what you are doing is this

```
put :elearning_course_removal, {study_group_id: study_group.id, id: course.id, current_user: user}
```

**params** tag is missing which could be the issue

Comment: thank you! changing params like this now is returning a "Route not found" error: "No route matches {:action=>"elearning_course_removal", :controller=>"courses", :params=>{:study_group_id=>"1", :id=>"1"}}"

although in my Routes i do have this: 

elearning_course_removal_study_group_course PUT
/study_groups/:study_group_id/courses/:id/elearning_course_removal(.:format)
courses#elearning_course_removal